# How do I change the ripple background color on Button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So far in the API (`v3.9.2`), I see a mention of `TouchRippleProps` for `ButtonBase` for https://material-ui.com/api/button-base/

My button looks like

```
<Button variant="text"
                  size={"large"}
                  fullWidth
                  className={classes.button}
          >
            {value}
          </Button>
```

and my button `style` is .

```
 button: {
    backgroundColor: colors.surface,
    borderRadius: 0, // to make buttons sharp edged
    touchRipple: colors.primary
  }
```

When I touch a button, I see a white background (see number `5`) as 
[image]
My question is that When I touch a button, how can I change that background from `white` to let's say `blue` and then let it fade away?

**UPDATE** . 
[image]

Comment: A CodeSandbox reproducing this would be helpful.

Comment: There are a number of ways to go about this, but it isn’t clear from your question what is causing the button to change to a white background and whether or not it stays white. Since this isn’t part of the default behavior, a sandbox showing the current behavior would make it easier to provide approaches that will actually work with the rest of your styles.

Comment: Thanks @RyanCogswell. The code sandbox is https://codesandbox.io/s/2ryy62zn0. However, when you open this up in the browser window, the issue does not pop up, but if you open this up in Mobile or Mobile View (with DevTools open), you can see this issue. The URL to demo is https://2ryy62zn0.codesandbox.io/

Comment: I have added the updated view based on https://2ryy62zn0.codesandbox.io/ URL from codesandbox. Thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieved reasonable behavior with the following changes to your `numberPadStyle`:

```
const numberPadStyle = theme => ({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: colors.surface,
    borderRadius: 0, // to make buttons sharp edged
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: colors.primary,
      // Reset on touch devices, it doesn't add specificity
      "@media (hover: none)": {
        backgroundColor: colors.surface,
        "&:active": {
          backgroundColor: colors.primary
        }
      }
    },
    "&:active": {
      backgroundColor: colors.primary
    }
  }
});
```

The issue with touch screens is that a touch triggers the "hover" effect and it doesn't go away till you touch somewhere else. `"@media (hover: none)"` targets the hover effect for touch devices (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover). The "active" CSS is in effect during the touch/click and then the ripple built in to `Button` takes care of the rest.

You can, of course, adjust the hover and active colors as desired.

[image: Edit Calculator]

Comment: This is great help @Ryan. I was not even close in my thinking about this issue. Thanks for educating me!

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't appear animations other than the ripple are supported. However, you can create something like this `TriggeredAnimation` wrapper component:

```
class TriggeredAnimationWrapper extends Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args)
    this.state = {
      wasClicked: false
    }
    this.triggerAnimation = this.triggerAnimation.bind(this)
  }

  triggerAnimation(callback) {
    return (...args) => {
      this.setState(
        {wasClicked: true}, 
        () => requestAnimationFrame(()=>this.setState({wasClicked: false}))
      )
      if (callback) return callback(...args)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      triggerAnimation,
      props: {
        children
      },
      state: {
        wasClicked
      }
    } = this.props
    return children({wasClicked, triggerAnimation})
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<TriggeredAnimationWrapper>({wasClicked, triggerAnimation}) => (
  <Button 
    onClick={triggerAnimation((e) => console.log('clicked', e))}
    className={wasClicked ? 'clicked' : ''}
  />
)</TriggeredAnimationWrapper>
```

Then, you can create a css animation and change the background when the click class is present.

Comment: Anybody wanna take a guess as to why this got downvotes? I'd like to improve it if I could figure out what was wrong?