# Material-UI button disappears after click

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a button which is disappearing when clicked on.  Also clicking the button once does not result in any button actions running.  I have to click the button and then click the area where the button was after it disappears for my button actions to take effect.

```
<Grid className={classes.container} style={{justifyContent: 'flex-end'}} item xs={12}>
            <Button className={classes.addImage} onClick={this.addPic}>
                <input 
                className={classes.takePic} 
                ref="file"
                id="takePic" 
                type="file" 
                accept="image/*"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                />
                Add 
                <br></br>
                Image

            </Button>
        </Grid>
```

Styling:

```
 addImage: {
    display: 'flex',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    color: 'white',
    borderRadius: 90,
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    justifySelf: 'flex-end',
    marginRight: '12.5%',
},
```

onChange function:

```
    onChange = () => {
    let newfile = this.refs.file.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let url = reader.readAsDataURL(newfile);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            openModal: true,
            imgSrc : [reader.result],
            imageType: newfile.type,
            newfile: newfile,
            filename: `${this.props.user.id}_${Date.now()}`
        })
        console.log(newfile)
        console.log(this.state)

    }
}
```

addPic function:

```
addPic = () => {
        document.getElementById('takePic').click()
    }
```

Comment: What does `this.addPic` and `this.onChange` do ? Can we see the functions ? Or a fiddle ?

Comment: I edited my post to include these functions.  I didn't include them in the original post because this issue was occurring before I created these functions.

Comment: An input tag within button tag??

Comment: @G_S now that you mention it, the input doesn't need to be on the button.  I will try moving that and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yrlle2)

Comment: @ZoltanToth I'm not sure this works for my app because I need the file input to access a devices camera when used from a mobile device.  Also I have used mat-ui buttons successfully in the past so I am really more concerned about why the issue is happening in this instance.

Comment: @tdammon Please share a CodeSandbox or similar with the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I've spent the past 30 minutes trying to recreate the issue in a jsfiddle and can't recreate.  If you want to see the error you can try clicking the 'Add Image' button here [link](http://beer-rating.herokuapp.com/#/beerrating  It works best from the mobile.

Comment: @tdammon When trying your link, the button does not disappear. There is however a pretty extreme hover effect that makes the button very light. On mobile, sometimes the "hover" (e.g. tooltip) is triggered by the first touch and then the second touch would register as a click, but I don't think Material-UI buttons work that way by default and I'm not able to reproduce the behavior you describe -- my first click works fine.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, That is interesting.  I am definitely seeing the button disappear, unless the hover is essentially white.  I am seeing the behavior you describe however it is intermittent.  Occasionally the first click does register as a click and runs the onClick functions (although the button still disappears).  Either way I appreciate you taking the time to look at this for me.

Comment: You may find the following answer helpful to prevent the "hover" look from staying on mobile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54526078/how-do-i-change-the-ripple-background-color-on-button/54543383#54543383

Comment: @RyanCogswell perfect! I won't be able to implement these fixes until I get home tonight but I feel confidant this will solve my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to be careful when overriding the CSS for the colors for Material-UI's `Button`. It is fairly easy to have an undesirable effect (particular on the "hover" state) on touch devices if you override the colors without following the pattern used within `Button`.

Below are excepts from `Button`'s styles that handle the colors for the "text" variant (the default):

```
export const styles = theme => ({
  /* Styles applied to the root element. */
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.text.primary,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['background-color', 'box-shadow', 'border'], {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.short,
    }),
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.text.primary, theme.palette.action.hoverOpacity),
      // Reset on touch devices, it doesn't add specificity
      '@media (hover: none)': {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      },
      '&$disabled': {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      },
    },
    '&$disabled': {
      color: theme.palette.action.disabled,
    },
  },
  /* Styles applied to the root element if `disabled={true}`. */
  disabled: {},
});
```

In your `addImage` class, you change the button's `backgroundColor` to black and `color` to white, but you don't handle what should happen on hover. Material-UI's styling will then win for hover due to specificity, and on touch devices (`'@media (hover: none)'`) the background will become transparent, but your change of `color` to "white" (instead of `theme.palette.text.primary`) will still be in effect which, if your page background is white, will mean that your button is now invisible.

You can fix this by being explicit about what should happen on hover as shown in my answer here: [How do I change the ripple background color on Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54526078/how-do-i-change-the-ripple-background-color-on-button/54543383#54543383).

`Button` source code (for full details on Material-UI's styling): https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js