# Material UI - disable hover:none media queries for all controls (all states)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Using a monitor with touch capabilities, I don't have hover styles on any controls.

When I hover over a Material UI button I get the following styles:

[image]

How can I disabled all @media (hover: none) styles, without overriding the styles for every control/every state?

I'm using **Material UI 3.9.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any easy way of doing this without explicitly overriding each use of `@media (hover: none)`, though it would be possible (though tedious) to override all of the different cases in your theme.

The following GitHub search should identify most of the components where this is in play: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/search?q=%22hover%3A+none%22&unscoped_q=%22hover%3A+none%22.

It would also be possible to create a JSS plugin that removes these styles. You can find an example [here](https://gist.github.com/adipascu/10f919b3daa18c2221de934f34f22bec) that is doing the reverse of what you want (i.e. it always applies the touch-screen styles).

My opinion is that you would be best off to leave this as is. If you override/remove those styles, you will have adverse effects on users who are using the touch screen and not a mouse since without those styles the hover effect will stick after a touch until a touch elsewhere occurs. The current solution in Material-UI is not ideal, but it is difficult for it to be done better without better support in the browser for detecting whether the user is using touch vs. mouse.

Related discussions/documentation:

- https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15000
- https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15736
- [How do I change the ripple background color on Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54526078/how-do-i-change-the-ripple-background-color-on-button/54543383#54543383)
- https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#jss-plugins

Comment: Thanks for the links, so disabling media queries is not a good idea, I will leave it as is. It only reproduces when the laptop is in tablet position (which is always in my case) even if the browser is on another monitor (non touch).

Answer (score 0):

This fix makes sure the styles using @media (hover: none) are only enabled when touch is used. It adds a touch-device class to the body tag, whenever touchstart has fired. Works on @material-ui/core v4.9.9

```
import { create } from 'jss';
import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const jss = create({
    plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, {
        onProcessRule: (rule, sheet) => {
            if(rule.type === 'style' && rule.options.parent.query === '@media (hover: none)'){
                rule.key = 'body.touch-device ' + rule.key;
                rule.selectorText = 'body.touch-device ' + rule.selectorText;
            }
            return rule;
        }
    }],
});

window.addEventListener('touchstart', function ontouchstart() {
    window.document.body.classList.add('touch-device');
    window.removeEventListener('touchstart', ontouchstart);
});

export default function HoverFix(props){
    return <StylesProvider jss={jss}>{props.children}</StylesProvider>
}
```